# C'est moi et pas toi qui ... ?

Tags: conjugaison

Comment conjugue-t-on les verbes après des sujets « mélangés » comme « moi et pas toi » ? Est-ce :

> C'est moi et pas toi qui suis professeur.

ou

> C'est moi et pas toi qui es professeur.

ou est-ce qu'on ne dit jamais de choses comme ça en français ?

(Je devine que c'est la première, puisque le sujet logique de le phrase, c'est moi. Mais peut-être que cela sonne mal de dire « suis » directement après « toi qui ».)

Comment: Je dirais: "C'est moi le professeur." en accentuant fortement le "moi".

Comment: L'intonation joue beaucoup, il faudrait au moins une virgule, mais avec la seconde version je comprends : qui s'y connaît le mieux ? C'est moi, et pas toi qui es pourtant professeur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> C'est moi et pas toi qui suis professeur.

Bien que les deux formulations soient étranges, je pense que ceci est la formulation correcte car, cela revient à mettre entre parenthèses le *et pas toi* qui relève du pléonasme. Le sujet de la phrase est donc *moi*. Le fait qu'on puisse déplacer le *et pas toi* du sujet sans altérer le sens de la phrase montre qu'il ne fait pas partie du sujet.

*C'est moi (et pas toi) qui suis professeur.

C'est moi qui suis professeur, et pas toi.*

L'accord du verbe se faisant avec le sujet, il faut donc d'après moi utiliser *suis*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord car, admettons que le "qui..." se rapporte à "toi", la phrase n'en serait pas une puisqu'elle ne comporterait pas de verbe mais seulement une subordonnée...! +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

En fait on peut dire les deux.

Dans la première formule on s'arroge le titre de professeur en le refusant à l'autre, dans la seconde on le dénie à l'autre pour se l'attribuer.

On utilise souvent la seconde formule, on fait l'accord 'naturellement' avec *toi* qui précède le *qui*.

Normalement, à la fin de la première phrase, il faudrait déplacer *et pas toi* en fin de phrase, pour une expression plus soutenue.

Comment: Un -1 non argumenté  ? Sauf erreur, l'un et l'autre se dit ou se dise ou au moins s'utilisent.

Comment: Je ne t'ai pas mis +1 ni -1 mais par contre je suis d'accord avec la réponse de @user2010913 plutôt qu'avec la tienne pour la raison que j'ai évoquée en commentaire de sa réponse... Désolée :-(

Comment: @Djouuuuh Merci pour ce commentaire. Savoir pourquoi on conteste ma réponse m'aide souvent à l'améliorer.

Comment: Oui c'est normal, c'est le but ici. Néanmoins, je n'ai pas downvoté car je ne la conteste pas forcément, dans le cas où on parlerait d'un bout de phrase plutôt que d'une phrase complète, peut-être(?).

Comment: Est-ce que les deux se diraient avec la deuxième personne du pluriel : *C'est moi et pas vous qui suis professeur.* ? vs *C'est moi et pas vous qui êtes professeurs.* ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Sans en être absolument certain : *C'est moi qui suis professeur* peut se dire mais me gène beaucoup : dire *moi-je* est très inélégant, et pour un professeur, un manque de finesse. *Je suis professeur et vous ne l'êtes pas* - En revanche *C'est moi et pas vous qui êtes professeurs* est moins gênant car il n'y a pas de moi-je, et la personne est voussoyée (ou vouvoyée selon votre humeur).  Il me semble que l'on ne peut employer cette formule qu'oralement, et qu'elle est très difficile à manier pour ne pas faire monter le ton de la conversation,.....

Comment: .....  pour ne pas mépriser l'interlocuteur, ce qui est une faute lourde, un signe d’incompétence (ou au moins de faiblesse) de la part d'un professeur, dont le plus grand travail est l'écoute, la prise en compte de l'instant, désamorcer tout conflit et malentendu pour ensuite adapter et transmettre son entièrement son message.

Answer (score 0):

From English,

> It's me, not you, who IS a professor

therefore

> C'est moi, pas toi, qui est professeur

should be the proper phrase.

Comment: Je pense que ce n'est pas le cas, au moins dans le français formel. Par exemple, on dit «c'est moi qui suis là. » C'est un exemple où on ne peut pas traduire les phrases mot par mot. Par exemple : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+moi+qui+suis%2C+c%27est+moi+qui+est&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20moi%20qui%20suis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20moi%20qui%20est%3B%2Cc0

Comment: No, French doesn't work like English here.