# Conjugaison de l'auxiliaire en passé composé

Tags: conjugaison, passé-composé

J'ai un doute:

C'est

> Hier c'est moi qui a décidé

ou

> Hier c'est moi qui ai décidé

Pourriez vous me dire la bonne réponse et pourquoi?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/549/moi-qui-fait-ou-moi-qui-fais, et dans un cas plus particulier : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/cest-moi-et-pas-toi-qui

Comment: Donc c'est moi qui ai décidé.

Comment: Au pluriel, la première forme donnerait « C'est nous qui ont décidé » qui est clairement incorrect.

Comment: @jlliagre « Ce sont nous qui ont décidé », si le sujet supposé de la première proposition est «c'est» non ? :)

Comment: @Random Non, et pourquoi pas tant qu'on y est « Ce sommes nous...» comme c'était l'usage en ancien français ;-) « C'est nous » est bien la forme correcte, comme d'ailleurs « C'est vous». On n'utilise pas « Ce sont nous » et « Ce sont vous » car le pluriel n'est employé avec « C'est » qu'à la troisième personne: « Ce sont eux...». « C'est eux...» est cependant aussi assez fréquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il faut simplement se demander où est le sujet.

Dans ce cas, c'est: ***moi*** donc implicitement c'est *je*.

D'où la réponse correcte:

> Hier c'est moi qui ai décidé